# How to pass information from a POST response back to the client NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express

I am currently trying to set up a EasyPost API and I need to store some information contained in a response from a POST route. I would like to send the data from the response straight to the client for storage, but I am unable to find out where or how to send the information.

This is my form receiving the information:

```
<div ng-controller="easypostController as epc" class="col l6">
    <!--  -->
        <h2>Customer address</h2>
        <form class="blue-grey darken-4">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.name" placeholder="Name">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.street1" placeholder="Street 1">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.street2" placeholder="Street 2">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.city" placeholder=" City">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.state" placeholder="State">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.zip" placeholder="Zip">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.country" placeholder="Country">
            <input ng-model="epc.address.phone" placeholder="Phone">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="epc.sendAddress()">Verify</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

This is the controller passing the information from the form to the factory:

```
 function easypostController(easypostFactory) {
    var epc = this

    epc.address = {}
    epc.sendAddress = function() {
    epc.resId = {}

        easypostFactory.send(epc.address)
            .then(function(res) {
                console.log("Successfullly sent address epc")
                // epc.resId = easypostFactory.resId
                epc.address = {}
            })
            // console.log(epc.resId)
    }
}
```

This is my factory that passes the information to the server:

```
address.send = function(address) {
        return $http.post(addressUrl, address)
        // epf.resId = address
        console.log(address, "=====")
    }
```

And this is where I am having issues, I am not able to get any res.send() function to send the response object back to the client side.

```
var address = easypost.Address.create(req.body, function(err, fromAddress) {
        var verifiedAddress = {}
        fromAddress.verify(function(err, response) {
            console.log("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=")
            if (err) {
                console.log('Address is invalid.')
            } else if (response.message !== undefined && response.message != null) {
                console.log('Address is valid but has an issue:', response.message)
                var verifiedAddress = response.address
            } else {
                verifiedAddress = response.address
                console.log(verifiedAddress)
                res.send(verifiedAddress)
            }

        })

    })
```

The verifiedAddress is the correct object as logged by my server I am just unable to send the response object to the client. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rather than use angular js for frontend, try to use a simple html form. here is the example :

```
<form name="simple" action="someurl" method="post"> <input type="text" name="username"> </form>
```

And you can get the value of the input text by these codes :

```
router.post("someurl", function(req,res){ var username = req.body.username }) console.log(username)
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Wilidan thanks for the reply, but my issue isn't with passing information from the client to the server it is passing the information back to the client after I get a response from my api POST call. My current solution is to store the POST response in a database then access the information from the database.     Thanks for the reply!